# Appcelerator Titanium - openFileChooserDialog does not exist: How to open a dialog to browse for a file?

Tags: javascript, file, titanium, appcelerator, file-browser

I currently have the following code:

```
function openFileChooser() {
    var options = {
        title : "Select file to upload to cloud...",
        types : ['mp3', 'm4a', 'aac', 'wav', 'aif', 'aiff'],
        typesDescription : "Audio files",
        path : Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory
    };

    //does not work
    Ti.UI.openFileChooserDialog(function(filenames) {
        fileSelected = filenames[0];
    }, options);

    $.filePath.text = fileSelected;
}
```

Basically, I am trying to open up a dialog for the user can browse for an audio file.  I have seen examples of `openFileChooserDialog` on several sites, but my app crashes when it runs, stating that it does not exist.

Is there anything I can do where I can open a dialog for the user to browse for an audio file?

Answer (score 0):

The openFileChooserDialog was part of the Titanium Desktop API, which was spun off to TideSDK.  If this is a mobile project, that API call doesn't exist in the mobile space.

Comment: So, what should I use as a replacement?